# MVC Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

This construction below using dropdownlist does not work!!

```
<% = Html.DropDownList (ddlUf, "All", New With (. Class = "text"})%>
```

It only works if I do this:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList (ddlUf, "All")%>
```

Or this:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList (ddlUf, Nothing, New With (. Class = "text"})%>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `new{ @class = "text"})`

Comment: Looks like he's using VB.NET to me.

Comment: for vb one could use New with { [Class] = "text" }

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the order of parameters mixed up.  Assuming that `ddlUf` is a string with the DropDownList name, and `"All"` is supposed to be the default option, then you need something like this:

```
<% =Html.DropDownList(ddlUf, Model.FullListOfSelectListItems, "All", New With (. Class = "text") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some parameter order/validity issues here. The Html.DropDownList() method works by taking the following:

string name - *assigns a name/id to the control*

SelectList selectList - *the list of options to appear in the drop down. You can construct this by creating a List and then using Linq to select the items from the list you want to appear in the drop down i.e:*

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

//Add items to appear in the drop down.
myList.Add("Item1");
myList.Add("AnotherItem");
...

//Select all the items from the list and place them into a SelectList object.
SelectList dropDownList = new SelectList(from items in myList select items);
```

string optionLabel - *the text for a default, empty item.*

object htmlAttributes - *a selection of HTML attributes to apply to the control.*

So in your example you might want to go for something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDown", Model.MyConstructedSelectList, "Default item", new { @class = "text" })
```

For more information on using drop down lists with models in MVC, see this blog post: 
http://277hz.co.uk/Blog/Show/10/drop-down-lists-in-mvc--asp-net-